# any client to be able to decrypt a mesage but not to create an encrypted message

Tags: encryption

I have an .Net Application and i want to this application which has some features. Depending client's domain and what features he wants i want to provide him a string which he will store it a file and will be accessible from the application.

I will create a second application which will get as parameters the domain and the features and it will produce the string.

Is there any way to encrypt this string with a key and my application (the first one mentioned)  to decrypt it?

I have in mind something like private/public key but reversing the logic. I mean, to encrypt the string from my second application wit the private key and the first application to decrypt it with the public key.

The purpose is the customer to not be able to change the string so that to change the available features.

PS i have an idea to use digital signature, but i dont know if i can have the public/private keys stored at xmlstrings. I think i have seen it somewhere (exporting/importing) but i am not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, digital signatures are the correct tool to use for this.

Storing the keys is a minor implementation detail.  Typically, such keys are natively represented as binary strings, possibly in [ASN.1](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One) or a similar encoding.  If you need to store the keys in some format that cannot handle arbitrary binary data, you can always e.g. [base64](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)-encode them first.

Comment: Ps. For a more detailed answer, you should specify which crypto library / API you're using.  The documentation for it will likely specify what signature algorithms its supports and the format used for reading/writing the keys.

Comment: Is it possible to store the keys permantly inside the code? I mean, like a string or in a suitable variiable?
I am thinking of producting applications public/private keys with my second application and then store that in side the Code

Comment: Yes, it is possible. If you want to do that to stop someone from just replacing the public key with their own, though, you should be aware that even keys embedded in compiled code can typically be changed e.g. using a hex editor. You can add some obfuscated checks in your code to try to detect any changes to the keys, but in general, if someone is determined enough to find a way to change the key, they'll always be able to. Or, if they really want it and are willing to spend enough effort, they could just reverse-engineer your code and reimplement it without any key checks.